# How to disable the login on local installation of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a local installation of Wordpress with same settings and plugins as in my website. I use the local WordPress installation to test the articles before posting in my website.

However, I would like to completely remove the login page in the WordPress. The idea is to directly go to the admin panel by using the URL :

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin.
```

Is is possible that we could completely disable the login in WordPress ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not? Without looking at the code I could guess you can hardcode the session values

Comment: why not just use the preview post mode to test your articles before going public rather than replicate the system else where oO

Comment: Well, I live in the part of the world where Internet is still considered luxury :) and not necessity. Having a local installation gives me independence and I can write it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You could add some javascript to auto enter the form and submit

```
$("#user_login").val("actualusername")
$("#user_pass").val("actualpassword");
$("#login_form").submit();
```

That's the easiest way i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in php by using wordpress's wp_signup function to log in. Just replace `'login'` and `'password'`.

And don't use this when working on a website that has 'localhost' in the domain name. :)

```
add_action( 'init', 'prf_auto_login' );
function prf_auto_login() {
    if ( ! is_admin() || is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    if(strpos(site_url(),'localhost') === false){
        return;
    }
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'login';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'password';
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();

    wp_redirect( esc_url( get_admin_url() ) ); exit;
}
```